# when i update angular2->4,use NoopAnimationsModule or BrowserAnimationsModule throw an error

Tags: javascript, angular

Error: BrowserModule has already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor from a lazy loaded module, import CommonModule instead

I'm sure my module is CommonModule not BrowserModule .

If I don't import BrowserAnimationsModule , it's ok.

But I need this,help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve my problem.

use BrowserAnimationsModule  in root.

I'll just leave the question here in case someone has the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for this my friend @Tao.L this help me. I got this issue with a lazy loaded module too. Is very strange this error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using 'NoopAnimationsModule' or 'BrowserAnimationModule', Which already contain 'BrowserModule' and loading your module lazily. SO the solution is Replace the BrowserModule with 'NoopAnimationModule or 'BrowserAnimationModule' in your 'app.module.ts'.

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AdminsModule } from './admins/admins.module';
import { NoopAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-
browser/animations';
//import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component'; 
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
    //BrowserModule,
    NoopAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule
],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```